# Trouble compiling Linux functions on Windows Dev Machine

Tags: go, compiler-errors, compilation

My app runs on a linux server, but I develop on a Windows machine.

I'm having problems compiling functions and types from the "golang.org/x/sys/unix" package. Here is a portion of my code not compiling well:

```
if runtime.GOOS == "linux" {
    var stat unix.Statfs_t
    err := unix.Statfs(mount, &stat)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Error: %v\n", err)
        continue
    }

    totalSpace = uint64(stat.Blocks) * uint64(stat.Bsize)
    freeSpace = uint64(stat.Bfree) * uint64(stat.Bsize)
}
```

I'm compiling using Goland from JetBrains. I get these errors: "undefined: unix.Statfs_t" and "undefined: unix.Statfs", "Compilation finished with exit code 2".

I imported the package with `go get -u "golang.org/x/sys/unix"`, but I still get this error. Anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 4):

Go source file package imports are processed by the compiler. A runtime check, `runtime.GOOS == "linux"`, is not going to work; it's too late. Use Go compiler [build constraints](https://pkg.go.dev/cmd/go#hdr-Build_constraints).

---

For both Linux and Windows, using both explicit and file name implicit build constraints,

`disk/disk.go`:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "path/filepath"
)

func main() {
    mount := string(filepath.Separator)
    total, free, err := DiskSpace(mount)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Fprintln(os.Stderr, err)
        os.Exit(1)
    }
    fmt.Println(total, free)
}
```

`disk/disk_linux.go`:

```
package main

import (
    "golang.org/x/sys/unix"
)

func DiskSpace(mount string) (total, free uint64, err error) {
    var stat unix.Statfs_t
    err = unix.Statfs(mount, &stat)
    if err != nil {
        return 0, 0, err
    }
    total = uint64(stat.Blocks) * uint64(stat.Bsize)
    free = uint64(stat.Bfree) * uint64(stat.Bsize)
    return total, free, nil
}
```

`disk/disk_windows.go`:

```
package main

import (
    "golang.org/x/sys/windows"
)

func DiskSpace(dir string) (total, free uint64, err error) {
    var (
        directoryName              = windows.StringToUTF16Ptr(dir)
        freeBytesAvailableToCaller uint64
        totalNumberOfBytes         uint64
        totalNumberOfFreeBytes     uint64
    )
    err = windows.GetDiskFreeSpaceEx(
        directoryName,
        &freeBytesAvailableToCaller,
        &totalNumberOfBytes,
        &totalNumberOfFreeBytes,
    )
    if err != nil {
        return 0, 0, err
    }
    return totalNumberOfBytes, totalNumberOfFreeBytes, nil
}
```

`disk/disk_other.go`:

```
//go:build !(linux || windows)

package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func DiskSpace(mount string) (total, free uint64, err error) {
    err = fmt.Errorf("DiskSpace not implemented for this OS")
    return 0, 0, err
}
```

On Linux:

```
disk$ go build && ./disk
64183046144 37856325632
$
```

On Windows:

```
disk>go build && disk.exe
205507317760 59385081856
>
```

---

You may want to consider using WSL for development.

> [Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/) lets developers run a GNU/Linux environment directly on Windows, unmodified, without the overhead of a traditional virtual machine or dual-boot setup.

---